# How to save 2d shapes in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to save a bunch 2d shapes (defined as positioned vertices) in  2d space (x y coordinates).

What is the best way to do it in c#?

Right now i'm saving them as lists of vertices:

```
       new Shape()
        {
            X = 20, //Position of the shape's top left corner on screen
            Y = 50, //Position of the shape's top left corner on screen
            Vertices = new List<Tuple<float, float>>() //This is a square
            {
                new Tuple<float, float>(0, 0),//Top left corner
                new Tuple<float, float>(0, 100), //Bottom left corner
                new Tuple<float, float>(100, 100),//Bottom right corner
                new Tuple<float, float>(100, 0)//Top right corner
            }
        }

      public class Shape
      {
          public float X;
          public float Y;
          public List<Tuple<float, float>> Vertices;
      }
```

Is there some better way to do that?

I need to be able to achieve two things with the saved shape:

Display it on the screen on the given x y (basically like absolute positioning in css) coordinates
And know the coordinates of each vertex in the shape

Comment: XML/Binary Serialization? json? your question as it stands is very broad. i.e What kind of project are you making? target platform? how is this list used?

Comment: I will be displaying those shapes on the screen in xaml in canvas, i'm basically working on a small game and i need to know the positions of the vertices in order to get my SAT collision detection to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to save your points as 'actual' points, but apart from that I don't think this could be 'saved' in any better way (That is, if by saving you mean storing them in memory).

Take a look at:

`System.Windows.Point` (For WPF).
or
`System.Drawing.Point` (For WinForms).

If you need to save them to disk, you may want to look in to some serialization, which technology you choose there is mostly up to taste and what you need, Performance? Space? etc.

ProtoBuf can be used to save relatively small files while still retaining pretty decent performance:
https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

Or you may want to use the built-in .NET XML serializer, or Binary serializer (Do note though that those are usually quite slow in comparison to other alternatives).

Also, if you want to save one line of code:

```
public class Shape
{
    public Point Position;
    public List<Point> Vertices;
}
```

Comment: I suppose I used poorly chosen wording, I need to define shapes, or "draw" shapes in the memory. To have their representation in the memory to work with. That point systems seem like the best available option, thanks.

Comment: Also, if you're working with WPF you may want to take a look at Bindings, although using Built-in WPF shapes like `Line` may hurt your performance in the end (WPF Is not very efficient at rendering large amounts of UIElements). If you need to render a large amount of objects and update them frequently, you may want to take a look at the `WriteableBitmap` class located in `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`. It acts like a BitmapSource, so you can bind directly to that from your UI.